# Sum the values for the same dates

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot a graph in `D3.js`. It is a Date VS value graph. But, few of my values are different when Date is same. I want to consider the summation of the values where Date is similar. This is how, Data looks like,

```
[

    {
        Date : "2017-12-15",
        Sales : "50"

    },
    {   Date : "2017-12-16",
        Sales : "20"

    },
    {
        Date : "2017-12-17",
        Sales : "30"
    },
    {
        Date : "2017-12-18",
        Sales : "10"
    },
    {
        Date : "2017-12-18",
        Sales : "40"
    },
    {
        Date : "2017-12-19",
        Sales : "60"
    }


]
```

As, you can see, on `2017-12-18` there are two `Sales` values, `10` and `40` . I want to consider the sum that is `(10 + 40)` for `2017-12-18` (Whenever there is a different `Sales` value for the same `Date`).

JS :-

```
var data = [

    {
        Date : "2017-12-15",
        Sales : "50"

    },
    {   Date : "2017-12-16",
        Sales : "20"

    },
    {
        Date : "2017-12-17",
        Sales : "30"
    },
    {
        Date : "2017-12-18",
        Sales : "10"
    },
    {
        Date : "2017-12-18",
        Sales : "40"
    },
    {
        Date : "2017-12-19",
        Sales : "60"
    }


].map(function(entry) {
  return {
    Date: d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(entry.Date),
    Sales: +entry.Sales
  }
});

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.Sales); });

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Date; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Sales; }));

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

g.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

g.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", line);
```

HTML :-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="600" height="180"></svg>
```

What is happening here is, it is taking the higher value only if Date is same, not taking the sum value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to sum the objects in that array. Probably, the most *idiomatic* way in JavaScript is using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var data = [{
  Date: "2017-12-15",
  Sales: "50"
}, {
  Date: "2017-12-16",
  Sales: "20"
}, {
  Date: "2017-12-17",
  Sales: "30"
}, {
  Date: "2017-12-18",
  Sales: "10"
}, {
  Date: "2017-12-18",
  Sales: "40"
}, {
  Date: "2017-12-19",
  Sales: "60"
}];

var reduced = data.reduce(function(allDates, date) {
  if (allDates.some(function(e) {
      return e.Date === date.Date
    })) {
    allDates.filter(function(e) {
      return e.Date === date.Date
    })[0].Sales += +date.Sales
  } else {
    allDates.push({
      Date: date.Date,
      Sales: +date.Sales
    })
  }
  return allDates
}, []);

console.log(reduced)
```

After that, it's just a matter of creating a basic SVG path:

```js
var rawData = [

  {
    Date: "2017-12-15",
    Sales: "50"

  }, {
    Date: "2017-12-16",
    Sales: "20"

  }, {
    Date: "2017-12-17",
    Sales: "30"
  }, {
    Date: "2017-12-18",
    Sales: "10"
  }, {
    Date: "2017-12-18",
    Sales: "40"
  }, {
    Date: "2017-12-19",
    Sales: "60"
  }


];

var data = rawData.reduce(function(allDates, date) {
  if (allDates.some(function(e) {
      return e.Date === date.Date
    })) {
    allDates.filter(function(e) {
      return e.Date === date.Date
    })[0].Sales += +date.Sales
  } else {
    allDates.push({
      Date: date.Date,
      Sales: +date.Sales
    })
  }
  return allDates
}, []);

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Date = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.Date)
})

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.Date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.Sales);
  });

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.Date;
}));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.Sales;
}));

g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

g.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

g.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr("d", line);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="180"></svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array#reduce` to sum `Sales` value of same date.

```js
var data = [{Date : "2017-12-15", Sales : "50"},{Date : "2017-12-16", Sales : "20"},{Date : "2017-12-17", Sales : "30"},{Date : "2017-12-18", Sales : "10"},{Date : "2017-12-18", Sales : "40"},{Date : "2017-12-19", Sales : "60"}];

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o.Date] = r[o.Date] || {Date: o.Date, Sales : 0};
  r[o.Date].Sales += +o.Sales;
  return r;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

```js
var data = [{Date : "2017-12-15", Sales : "50"},{Date : "2017-12-16", Sales : "20"},{Date : "2017-12-17", Sales : "30"},{Date : "2017-12-18", Sales : "10"},{Date : "2017-12-18", Sales : "40"},{Date : "2017-12-19", Sales : "60"}];

var data = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o.Date] = r[o.Date] || {Date: o.Date, Sales : 0};
  r[o.Date].Sales += +o.Sales;
  return r;
},{}));

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Date = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.Date)
})

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.Date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.Sales);
  });

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.Date;
}));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.Sales;
}));

g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

g.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

g.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr("d", line);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="180"></svg>
```

Comment: This is great and helped me solve my problem, thank you! But would you care to explain whats happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the values using [d3.nest()](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#nest) with rollup and sum functions.

```js
var data = [
    {Date : "2017-12-15", Sales : "50"},
    {Date : "2017-12-16", Sales : "20"},
    {Date : "2017-12-17", Sales : "30"},
    {Date : "2017-12-18", Sales : "10"},
    {Date : "2017-12-18", Sales : "40"},
    {Date : "2017-12-19", Sales : "60"}
]

var nested = d3.nest()
               .key(function(d) {
                 return d.Date;
               })
               .rollup(function(v) {
                 return d3.sum(v, function(d) {
                   return d.Sales;
                 });
               })
               .entries(data);

console.log(nested);
```

The resulting array looks like:

```
[
{key: "2017-12-15", value: 50},
{key: "2017-12-16", value: 20},
{key: "2017-12-17", value: 30},
{key: "2017-12-18", value: 50},
{key: "2017-12-19", value: 60}
]
```

The thing to watch out for is the nested objects now use "key" and "value" as the keys.